# How to change router by typescript in angular2?

Tags: angular, angular-new-router

For example, I use router-link like this:

```
<li><a [router-link]="['/start']">Start</a></li>
```

But  how can I change the router to /start by typescript?

Comment: Here is a routing example: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/routing-in-angular-2.0

Answer (score 4):

Small update related to hash location strategy.

In recent versions of angular2 the `bind` method is deprecated so you can change location strategy by using `provide` method.

```
bootstrap(MyApp, [
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy})
]);
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe you're asking how to configure your routes in Angular 2.

- 1) import & load your router
- 2) Use @RouteConfig to setup your routes on a component
- Optional: Add a hashbang (#) to your url

Here's an example:

```typescript
import {Component, View, bind, bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {routerInjectables, routerDirectives, Router, RouteConfig} from 'angular2/router';
import {LocationStrategy, Location, HashLocationStrategy } from 'angular2/router'; // options2: HTML5LocationStategy

// Components
import {Home} from 'home';
import {SomewhereElse} from 'somePlace';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-name'
})
@View({
  template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>',
  directives: [routerDirectives]
})
@RouteConfig([
  {path: '/start', as:  component: Home},
  {path: '/place/:placeId', component: SomewhereElse}
])
class AppName {}

bootstrap(AppName, [
  routerInjectables,
  bind(LocationStrategy).toClass(HashLocationStrategy) // for hashbang routes (/#/)
  // alternative: use HTML5LocationStrategy
]);
```

Comment: came here looking for how to setup hashbang routes and found this, even though it was not part of the question - thanks :)

Comment: And as per @shmck's helpful answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32003957/1450420) `routerInjectables` was changed to `ROUTER_PROVIDERS`

Comment: To those who are at the very beginning of their journey to the fabulous world of Angular 2: order does matter - `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` should go before `LocationStrategy`. Otherwise it wont work. (spent an hour figuring this out)