# Angular2 + Typescript1.5 Routing

Tags: angular, typescript1.5

I am trying to run a test application to understand how the routing in AngularJS2 works. I tried the following code:

```
/// <reference path="reference.ts" />

import { Component, View, bootstrap } from 'angular2/angular2'
import { Location, RouteConfig, RouterLink, Router, RouterOutlet } from 'angular2/router';
import { routerInjectables, Pipeline } from 'angular2/router';
import { Directive, Attribute, ElementRef, DynamicComponentLoader} from 'angular2/angular2';

import { DrinksService}  from 'services'

import { Drinkers } from 'components/drinkers'
import { Drinks } from 'components/drinks'
import { Contact } from 'components/contact'

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app'
})

@View({
    directives: [RouterOutlet, RouterLink],
    template: `
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a router-link="drinks">Drinks</a></li>
        <li><a router-link="drinkers">Drinkers</a></li>
        <li><a router-link="contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <main>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </main>
  `
})

@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/', component: Contact, as: 'contact'},
    { path: '/drinks', component: Drinks, as: 'drinks'},
    { path: '/drinkers', component: Drinkers, as: 'drinkers'}
])

class MyAppComponent {
    name:string
    buttonName:string
    showup:boolean

    constructor(public router: Router) {
        this.name = 'Alice and Bob'
        this.buttonName = 'are going to see rabbit whole'
        this.showup = true
    }

    goToDrink = () => {
        alert('Sicher?')
        this.showup = false
    }

    isVisible = () => {
        return !this.showup
    }

    goToDrinkReally = () => {
        this.router.parent.navigate('/home')
    }

}

bootstrap(MyAppComponent, [routerInjectables])
```

index.html:

```
<!-- index.html -->
<html>
<head>
    <title>Angular 2 Quickstart</title>
    <script src="https://github.jspm.io/jmcriffey/bower-traceur-runtime@0.0.87/traceur-runtime.js"></script>
    <script src="https://jspm.io/system@0.16.js"></script>
    <script src="angular25minutes/angular25minutes.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- The app component created in app.ts -->
<my-app></my-app>
<script>System.import('app')</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Everything compiles but in the browser I am getting empty screen. As html I can see only

```
<html><head>
    <title>Angular 2 Quickstart</title>
    <script src="https://github.jspm.io/jmcriffey/bower-traceur-runtime@0.0.87/traceur-runtime.js"></script><style type="text/css"></style>
    <script src="https://jspm.io/system@0.16.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://jspm.io/es6-module-loader@0.16.6.js" data-init="upgradeSystemLoader"></script>
    <script src="angular25minutes/angular25minutes.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- The app component created in app.ts -->
<my-app></my-app>
<script>System.import('app')</script>

</body></html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

And sometimes after compilation in the console shows up following problem:

ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No base href set. Either provide a binding to "appBaseHrefToken" or add a base element.

but it is quite random.

Comment: See https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/3122

Comment: Thanks it works now. Btw this router can be used also with angular1, can't it?

Comment: To be really honest I don't know :/

Comment: Do you have base href set in html head? Example: <head><base href="/"></head>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few issues here:

It doesn't seem that you're loading the router files. They can be found at [code.angularjs.org](https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.34/router.dev.js), among other places.

For a more complete view on how to use the Angular 2 router checkout the [Meteor-Angular2 Tutorial](http://angular-meteor.com/tutorials/angular2/routing-and-multiple-views).

Currently the default HTML5LocationStrategy seems to have a lot of issues, I would suggest setting the HashLocationStrategy in your app.

In your root app file, import the necessary files:

```
import {
  Component,
  View,
  bootstrap,
  provide
} from 'angular2/angular2'
import {
  LocationStrategy,
  HashLocationStrategy
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
} from 'angular2/router';
```

Then bind to the location when bootstrapping:

```
bootstrap(MyAppComponent, [
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  provide(LocationStrategy).toClass(HashLocationStrategy)
]);
```

**Update**

- `routerInjectables` was changed to `ROUTER_PROVIDERS`
- `bind` was changed to `provide`

*Source:*

- [angular@2.0.0-alpha.41/CHANGELOG.md](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-alpha41-2015-10-13)

Comment: Finally I managed to configure it. You can see my project here https://github.com/lrzeszotarski/angular2-in-5minutes. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: It appears the provide method has changed in the beta release. Try this.                                                            bootstrap(MyAppComponent, [
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy})
]);