# Angular2 routing alpha 46 routes forward (with a Console error), but not back to home

Tags: typescript, angular, atom-editor

I am experimenting with Angular2, alpha46, and using atom-typescript 7.7.2  I finally got it to route forward to a sub-page, but it does not correctly route back when I click the Back button. The Console error is - postApartment4Rent has no route configuration. But the command line changes to show the originating index.html URL, but the page does not automatically refresh. When I click the Refresh, the index.html page loads. The Home component seems absent. Additionally, atom-typescript has the error - router has no exported member ROUTER_PROVIDERS - though angular2 seems to find and work with it.  Here's relevant code for app.ts, index.html, and postApartment4Rent.ts The home.ts file is currently identical to postApartment4Rent.ts except for the component name.

index.html

```
<residence-app><h1>Loading . . .</h1></residence-app>
<!--other stuff-->
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.46/angular2.dev.js"></script> <!--Must be after the 2 ES6 & System.config above -->
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.46/router.dev.js"></script>
```

app.ts

```
/// <reference path="../angular2-oPost/typings/angular2/angular2.d.ts" />
"use strict";
import { Component, View, bootstrap, Directive, bind, Inject } from "angular2/angular2";
import { ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  Router,
  RouterOutlet,
  RouteConfig,
  RouterLink,
  Location
 } from 'angular2/router';

import { Home } from "./src/components/navigation/home";
import { PostApartment4Rent } from "./src/components/navigation/postApartment4Rent";
@Component({
  selector: 'residence-app'
})
@View({
  templateUrl: "angular2-oPost/src/components/navigation/headerFooter.html",
  styleUrls: ["angular2-oPost/src/commonStyles/headerFooter.css"],
  directives: [ RouterOutlet, RouterLink, Home, PostApartment4Rent ]
})
@RouteConfig( [
  { path: "/home", as: "Home", component: Home },
  { path: "/postApartment4Rent ",  as: "PostApartment4Rent", component: PostApartment4Rent } 
] )
class ResidenceApp {
  router: Router;
  location: Location;
  constructor(router: Router, location: Location) { this.router = router; this.location = location; }
}
bootstrap( ResidenceApp, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS] );
```

headerFooter.html has several divs and the following tag to insert partial page components

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

postApartment4Rent.ts should insert a component into router-outlet in headerFooter.html, if I understand routing correctly

```
"use strict";
import { Component, View, bootstrap, Directive } from "angular2/angular2";
import { RouterLink } from 'angular2/router';
@Component({
  selector: "residence-app"  //is this correct?
})
@View({
  template: `
  <div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
      <li><a [router-link]="['./Home']">Home Page</a></li>
      <li><a [router-link]="['./PostApartment4Rent']">Rent Apartment input link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <main>
    < router-link ></router-link >
  </main>
<h1>PostApartment4Rent is under construction</h1>
`,
directives: [ RouterLink ]
})
export class PostApartment4Rent {
}
```

Comment: Change `['./Home']` to `['../Home']` and `['./PostApartment4Rent']` to `['../PostApartment4Rent']` this way it will route one level up (the `./` makes it relative to the route, `PostApartment4Rent` in this case, which has no routing).

Comment: Eric, thank you.  These changes are part of the fix. I no longer get the Console error about '...has no route configuration'. But when I click the back button, the URL changes but the new page does not load. I have to manually refresh. Thanks, though.

Comment: By default router uses `PathLocationStrategy`, so if you add `bootstrap( ResidenceApp, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS, provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy})] );` you'll be good to go (*Don't forget to import `provide`, `LocationStrategy` and `HashLocationStrategy`*)

Comment: Eric, I tried your bootstrap code. I import from angular2/router. The page loads and routes forward, but the back button only changes the URL.  The page has to be manually refreshed to get the back page content. Continuing problem.  Another source says the project is stuck on alpha.36, does not receive ROUTER_PROVIDERS, and hence doesn't work. Console says - GET 
https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.46/angular2.dev.js . . . [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 72ms]  What's going on and why?

Comment: Note: the above Console message is from Firefox.  Chrome tells me alpha.46 is loaded/active.  The routing behavior is the same in both browsers.

Comment: Ignore my comment 2 above about - HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified.  I figured it out and it has nothing to do with this routing problem.

Comment: Solved the atom-typescript problem - no exported member - by removing ROUTER_PROVIDERS, etc. from imports. Page loads and routes forward, but not backward.